# Text file processing with not precise enough timestamps

Tags: perl, file, loops, timestamp

I have two text files, each with a first column containing timestamps covering the same time but not at the same rate (the second file has much more samples). However, because of a lack of precision, some of the data I collected (which are in the other columns of those text files) vary within the same timestamp.

For example, this is an excerpt of the second file

```
Timestamp RobotYaw
1375448725 -2.183439
1375448725 -2.173082
1375448725 -2.169424
```

and of the first file :

```
Timestamp State
1375448725 8
1375448725 9
```

What I want to do is to create an output file which is a copy of the second file (which has more samples) but with an extra column specifying the current state (which is given in the first file). In the situation above however, because timestamps are not precise enough, I am unaware of when the change from state 8 to 9 happened, and I have chosen to have the first half of the samples with that timestamp having state 8, and the other half state 9.

I am struggling on doing that with Perl. Right now, it will always give the latest state available (9) for all samples with that timestamp...

Here is a skeleton of the current program with only the minimum kept (this should print all timestamps from the second file along with the current state) :

```
my $state = 1;

while ( my $ligne = <SECONDFILE> )
{
    my ( $timestamp , $junk ) = split ( /\s/ , $ligne ) ;

    while ( my $checkline = <FIRSTFILE> )
    {
        my ( $stateTimestamp , $stateJunk ) = split ( /\s/ , $checkline ) ;
        if ( int($timestamp) < int($stateTimestamp) )
        {
            last;
        }
        else
        {
            $state = $stateJunk;
        }
    }
    print OUTPUT $timestamp;
    print OUTPUT " ";
    print OUTPUT $state;
    print OUTPUT "\n";
}
```

Would you have any idea how I could easily handle this arbitrary change of state within one timestamp ? As it is quite hard to explain, thank you for reading and if you have any question, I'd be happy to explain further...

Comment: I think you explained it adequately.  Given multiple samples and multiple states you want the states distributed equally across the samples.  You need to specify how to handle edge cases (more states than samples, for instance), and how to distribute the remainder when the number of states doesn't divide the number of samples evenly.

Comment: Actually, this issue arrises only when there is a change of state within the same timestamp in file one. In this case, I indeed made the choice to distribute the states equally in the second file for samples corresponding to that timestamps. In other cases, I don't need to do this and the state I acquire using my code is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

To know what sample to print for which yaw timestamp, we will need to read in each file into a hash. We can count how many yaw timestamps and how many sample timestamps so we can math out what sample to use. This should hopefully work:

```
    my %first_file;
    my %second_file;

    ### Store in a hash the unique timestamp|state values in order. 
    while ( my $checkline = <FIRSTFILE> ) {
        my ( $stateTimestamp, $statenum ) = split /\s/, $checkline;
        $first_file{$stateTimestamp}{'number'}++;
        my $count = $first_file{$stateTimestamp}{'number'};
        $first_file{$stateTimestamp}{$count} = $statenum;
    }

    ### Store timestamp and yaw values
    while ( my $ligne = <SECONDFILE> ) {
        my ( $timestamp , $robotyaw ) = split /\s/, $ligne;
        $second_file{$timestamp}{'number'}++;
        $second_file{$timestamp}{$robotyaw} = $second_file{$timestamp}{'number'};
    }

    ### MATH TIME IS FUN TIME. Don't forget to sort those hashes!
    foreach ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %second_file ) {
        my $tstamp = $_;
        my $valhash = $second_file{$tstamp};
        my $change_count = round_up($second_file{$tstamp}{'number'} / $first_file{$tstamp}{'number'});
        foreach ( sort { ${$valhash}{$a} <=> ${$valhash}{$b} } keys %{$valhash} ) {
            my $yaw = $_;
            if ($yaw eq 'number') { next; }
            my $state_num = round_up(${$valhash}{$yaw} / $change_count);
            print OUTPUT "$tstamp $yaw ", $first_file{$tstamp}{$state_num}, "\n";
        }
    }    

    ### We could have used POSIX's ceil here instead  
    sub round_up {
        my $n = shift;
        return(($n == int($n)) ? $n : int($n + 1));
    }
```

You should also get used to using the 3 parameter open filehandle::

```
open my $firstfile, '<', 'first_file.txt' or die "Can't open first file: $!";
open my $output, '>', 'output_file.txt' or die "Can't open output file: $!";
```

This way they are scoped properly.